# Trouble with translation 「アジア人歌手では過去最大級となる。」

Tags: grammar, translation, particles

Reading a newspaper article I came across a sentence which gives me multiple troubles...

> 昨春に始まったツアーは日米や東南アジアなど１３カ国・地域で１４０万人を集める見通し。アジア人歌手では過去最大級となる。

Regarding では, would it be correct to treat it like "concerning" "in regard to"?
Also I am not sure how to translate 過去最大級 and the function of と in となる。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「アジア[人歌手]{じんかしゅ}**では**[過去]{かこ}[最大級]{さいだいきゅう}となる。」

In this context, 「では」≒「の[中]{なか}では」 = "**among** (all Asian singers)"

「過去最大級」 means "***of the largest scale so far***".

「～～**と**なる」 is a little bit more formal way of saying 「～～**に**なる」, but 「～～となる」 here does not really mean "to become ~~".  It means basically the same thing as 「～～である」 = as in "A is B.", "A will be B.", etc.

In addition, the subject of the sentence is unmentioned (as usual).

> "It will be of the largest scale ever among all Asian singers."

"It" refers to the scale of the concert tour.