# ってなる what does it mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I often come across ってなる in informal contexts, but I don't exactly know how to understand it. I think it is like となる in casual speech but it doesn't really make sense in some sentences. For example :

> 殺すぞ！ってなる

I feel like it's pretty much the same as saying for example :

> 殺すぞと言う場面になる

But in an informal way, but I would like it if someone can confirm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence means 「殺すぞという**気持ち**になる」. So this ～ってなる means something like "will come to feel like ～ (because of something previously mentioned)".

I don't know whether this usage is listed in serious dictionaries, but this kind of ～ってなる is fairly common in casual speech.

Examples:

> - 夏休みが明けると、学校に行きたくない**ってなる**。
> - えー**ってなった**。 It surprised me. / It turned me off. (えーっ ≒ oh no)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what it comes from ? I doubt it is となる　but If you can confirm that would be nice!

Comment: @Tchang Yes, ～となる can mean exactly the same, e.g. "殺すぞとなる", "えー、となる". となる is less colloquial, and となる has various other usages including something like [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32208/5010).